# I'm trying to use SVN instead of dropbox

Tags: svn, dropbox

I was going to buy a dropbox account since I really need one, but then I asked myself "Why not using SVN for this?"

So I setup a SVN server on my Debian server. Then installed TortoiseSVN on my Windows desktop and Versions on my Apple laptop.

I tried creating cronjobs on Windows to `/command:update` and `/comment:commit` every hours but here are some problems I've encountered:

- If I delete a file, I have to do it through `TortoiseSVN | Delete` and I can't delete it like it's a normal file.
- If I have a `*.txt` on the server but a more recent one on my machine, TortoiseSVN doesn't know what to do when I update. How do I precise I want it to keep only the last one edited?

Am I doing this wrong? Should I just write a script to "watch" the folder and sync it?

Comment: Subversion is *not* an automated backup program.

Comment: why not use it as such? I read that dropbox was based on SVN.

Comment: @David天宇Wong SVN is the version control system, not a storage. While dropbox may be based on SVN, it's still higly adjusted for it's specific purpose -- online storage with sync and a bit of versioning features. Using pure SVN as a dropbox is a perversion.

Answer (score 2):

You may want investigate [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/), which is an open-source Dropbox alternative that uses `git` as its transport and versioning system.  There are clients for Windows, Linux, and OS X.

Comment: wow, this seems neat. Do you happen to use it? What's your take on it?

Comment: I'm reading through it and it doesn't comment on data encryption. I really wonder how it's done, because I know SVN or dropbox are trustworthy on that.

Comment: Subversion does not offer data encryption of its filestore.  Dropbox has even less security -- any Dropbox employee is able to view your data.  The primary advantage to running a Dropbox clone yourself is that you have much more control over where the data is located and who has access to it.  Like Subversion, Git can operate over an encrypted channel, such as `ssh` or `https`.

Comment: I use Sparkleshare to keep some files in sync between my desktop at work and my laptop, but honestly it has not replaced Dropbox for me because Dropbox has facilities that allow sharing specific folders with other people.  This functionality is not available in Sparkleshare.

Comment: Also it seems very buggy to change the default location folder, which doesn't work at all on my computer and since my default drive is a SSD it's a big no. Any alternatives to sparkleshare?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use SVN for something that it was not designed to do.  The whole point of a repository is that you are careful about what you commit and what you delete.  It is there to track incremental changes to documents.

You are going to have to start using SVN in the way SVN is meant to be used.  That is:

- your documents are hosted on your server;
- you check out / update the latest version from the server before you make any local changes;
- you use SVN delete to remove documents that are no longer required;
- you commit your changes back to the server when you are done editing.

If that's inconvenient or doesn't suit your purposes, I suggest you find software that is designed to do what DropBox does.  Oh, I see an answer has just been provided with a suggested product to try.

Comment: I'm pretty sure dropbox was built ON svn

Comment: I'm fairly certain that is not the case.

Comment: My point is that the expectation of SVN to behave like DropBox without using DropBox is invalid.